# map.addLayer is not a function

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I´m creating a map from a WMS with time dimension.

The user should have the opportunity to change the time, so that other features are displayed on the map.

I have a start time and the user should fill an input-field with his desired time.

A string will be created containing the time in the right format.

With that time another layer should be generated and just be laid over the existing layer.

```
function CreateLayer(myOtherTime)
        {


            var newlayer =  new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
              url: 'http://webgis-kogge.auf.uni-rostock.de:8080/geoserver/sm/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=sm:twit_corp_live_test&time='+myOtherTime


              })

            });


            map.addLayer(newlayer);
        }
```

Problem: I get the error message: map.addLayer is not a function.

The map is created in the following:

```
function CreateMap(center, myTime){

          new ol.Map({
            layers: [
              new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()}),
              new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
              url: 'http://webgis-kogge.auf.uni-rostock.de:8080/geoserver/sm/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=sm:twit_corp_live_test&time='+myTime
              })
              })
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
              center: center,
              zoom: 11.2
            }),
            target: 'map'
          });
```

Comment: did you define `map` any where? may be if you add that section of code too we could help

Comment: @iant I just updated the question, sorry for inconvenience, it´s my first time using stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you haven't defined map and you are using it; in your `CreateMap` function add a return statement at the end:

```
return map;
```

and then declare a global variable called map in your code :

```
var map = CreateMap(...);
```

now you'll have a reference of your map where the function `addLayer` is defined

Comment: your supposed answer would work, but now i get the error message: "Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined"

is this caused by a missing js library?

'<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script> ' 
this is, what I embedded

Comment: It worked now. Just tried a little bit and I understand it now.